# How about evaluating an estimator using the VARIANCE of loss (instead of the expectation of loss)?

Tags: optimization, loss-functions, risk

The risk of an estimator $\delta$ is defined as $$E_\theta[L(\theta,\delta(X))],$$
where, say, $L(\theta,\delta(X)) = (\theta-\delta(X))^2$, and $E_\theta(X)$ is defined as $\int XdP_\theta$, namely the expectation of random variable $X$ when the parameter is $\theta$.

I wonder why people never considered $$Var_\theta[L(\theta,\delta(X))]$$ **in addition to** the risk as a way to evaluate an estimator given a predefined loss function?

Say $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ have similar risk, but different variance of loss. Intuitively I would choose the one with a smaller variance of loss. However, I've never seen people ever talked about it. Have they?

Comment: That would make a very precise but inaccurate predictor look very good. For example, if I consistently predict tomorrow's temperature to be exactly 20 degrees too high, the variance of the difference would be 0.
A precise but inaccurate predictor needs to be calibrated.

Comment: @RobbytheBelgian I understand. My question is "in addition" to the expectation of loss. Suppose two estimators give the same expectation of loss for some $\theta$, then why people never consider using their variances of loss to further pick the best of these two?

Comment: It would essentially mean using a different loss function. By changing the loss function you can penalize occasional high errors more.
Choosing the correct loss function for a given problem is not trivial. Any crucial risk assessment needs to be taken into account.

Comment: Yes, I hear you. However, we always predefined a loss before we talk about the quality of an estimator, e.g. squared loss for the risk of an estimator. We basically assess an estimator under a specific loss.

Comment: It's an interesting question. You would, effectively, optimize an estimator that balances the error across samples (not one that achieves minimal error overall). Perhaps you can frame it along the likes of a loglikelihood too

Answer (score 1):

I saw something similar in two papers:

- [A Maurer & M Pontil. Empirical Bernstein Bounds and Sample Variance Penalization. 2009](https://arxiv.org/abs/0907.3740)
- [JC Duchi & H Namkoong. Variance-based regularization with convex objectives. 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02581)

The second one is more on point (and easier to read to me).

They consider the following problem statement:
minimize the empirical risk given by
$$R(\theta):=\mathbb E[\ell(\theta,x)]$$

The following provides a lower-bound, given a sample $X$ from the population $x$ and a parameter space $\Theta$:

$$R(\theta)\leq\mathbb E[\ell(\theta,X)] + C_1 \sqrt\frac{\operatorname{Var}(\ell(\theta,X))}{n}+\frac{C_2}{n} \quad \forall \quad \theta \text{ in } \Theta$$

According to authors, the bound can be interpreted in regards to the bias-variance tradeoff.
They then use this bound to define a robustly regularized risk.

Comment: It looks that the paper is not assessing an estimator but rather to estimate $\theta$ given $X$ using risk.

Comment: @Tan true, but the lower bound is still true (given the constraints), even though it's not the main point of the paper.